# How do you do alias in Select method (LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to alias the string list with a named column:

```
var providers = EMRRepository.GetProviders().Select(x => x as name);
```

where '`GetProviders()`' returns a `List<string>`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's called a "Projection", just select a new anonymous type.

```
var projection = data.Select( x => new { FieldName = x.Property } );
```

Comment: but what If you needed the aliases to be right in the sql query ?

Comment: @JohnSmith the SQL alias should be as simple as 'SELECT [Column] AS [Alias]', no?

Comment: Yes:), but I need to write a LINQ query which will transale to SQL with certain alias, is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to select into a new anonymous type.

```
var providers = EMRRepository.GetProviders().Select(x => new { Name = x });
```