# how to Convert left and right outer join Sql to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

i recently purchased a tool [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/help) which can convert the SQL query to LINQ but it can not convert the Right or left Join of SqL. Can please explain me that how to Convert Right and left outer join using SQL to Linq? and also is Linq Support Aliases for example in this query "tblaccounts as tb1"

**Here is my query**

```
SELECT   ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY  MAIN.CHASSIS_NO asc) as S#,    MAIN.CHASSIS_NO, MAIN.AVAILABILITY, MAIN.ID AS REF#, tblCar_Location.CAR_LOCATION AS LOCATION, MAIN.STOCK_TYPE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 
                      MAIN.purchasedate, 105) AS DATE, 


                      CONVERT(VARCHAR(17), COST.TOTAL_COST, 1) AS TOTAL_COST,

                       SPEC.OPTIONS, CONVERT(VARCHAR(17), COST.O_P_YEN, 1) 
                      AS O_P_YEN, CAST(MAIN.ID AS varchar(10)) AS ID2, MAIN.file_ref, PAPER.TEMP, SPEC.MODEL, SPEC.TRANSMISSION, tblcolor.color, 
                      tblmake_details.model_description, tblmake.make, tblcompany.C_Code, CONVERT(VARCHAR(17), COST.Selling_Price, 1) AS SELLING_PRICE, 
                      SPEC.make_category_ID, tblvehicle_category.CATEGORY, SPEC.FUEL_TYPE, MAIN.purchase_ref_ID, MAIN.ENTRY_DATE, MAIN.thirdParty_ID, tblaccounts.ACCOUNT, 
                      MAIN.vendor_ID, tb1.ACCOUNT, tb1.field2 as contact_no, tb1.contactDetails  as mobile_no,tb1.field1 as contact_address, CONVERT(VARCHAR(17), 
                      COST.O_P, 1) AS O_P, CONVERT(VARCHAR(17), COST.O_P_rate, 1) AS O_P_rate,
                          (SELECT     SUM(amount) AS Expr1
                            FROM          tblexpense
                            WHERE      (stock_ID = MAIN.ID) AND (Account_ID = 34)) AS CC_exp,
                          (SELECT     SUM(amount) AS Expr1
                            FROM          tblexpense AS tblexpense_1
                            WHERE      (stock_ID = MAIN.ID) AND (Account_ID = 37)) AS ME_exp, MAIN.COMMENTS, DATEDIFF(day, MAIN.ENTRY_DATE, GETDATE()) AS Days_Over, 
                      currency_master.currency_short_name,PAPER.CONSIGNMENT_NO AS CONT_NO,
                      purchase_ID,

                      CONVERT(VARCHAR(17), COST.fake_TOTAL_COST, 1) AS fake_TOTAL_COST

FROM         currency_master RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      COST ON currency_master.ID = COST.currency RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      tblcompany RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      tblaccounts RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      MAIN LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tblaccounts as tb1 ON MAIN.vendor_ID = tb1.ID ON tblaccounts.ID = MAIN.thirdParty_ID ON tblcompany.C_ID = MAIN.c_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tblCar_Location ON MAIN.LOCID = tblCar_Location.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tblcolor RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      tblvehicle_category RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      SPEC ON tblvehicle_category.category_ID = SPEC.make_category_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tblmake ON SPEC.make_ID = tblmake.make_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tblmake_details ON SPEC.model_description_ID = tblmake_details.ID ON tblcolor.color_id = SPEC.color_ID ON MAIN.ID = SPEC.ID ON 
                      COST.ID = MAIN.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      PAPER ON MAIN.ID = PAPER.ID
WHERE    (MAIN.file_ref NOT LIKE 'J%') AND (MAIN.Po_Flag = 1) and MAIN.ISACTIVE=1
```

Comment: Check this link out http://itworksonmymachine.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/sql-to-linq-cheat-sheet/

Comment: As for column alias check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418692/how-do-you-do-alias-in-select-method-linq

Comment: Check this out as well for right outer join http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/show/1849/how-to-use-left-right-outer-join-in-linq

Comment: Thanks summer for these links!